# Trigger with subctration from row before

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to set a column with the code below:

```
declare before int;

set before = (
        select X.delivery
        from delivery as X
        where X.delivery_id < NEW.delivery_id LIMIT 1
        );
set NEW.delivery_col = before + 1;
```

My goal is to get one row before the new one and set the value plus 1;

If I set the variable with a number (Example: 2) it works but it is not working with the select.

Any idea where I am messing?

Comment: One thing is there isn't an order by in your select, so you'll get the first record, not the most recent.

Comment: Is this inside an insert or update trigger?

Comment: @Sloan - I need to use it in an "Insert" and "Update"

Comment: What returns or should the query (`select X.delivery ...`) return?

Comment: I need to return the value for the row before the new one.

Comment: Just add an order by clause on the key descending. That will get you the record before the current one.

Comment: @Sloan - It did't work: SET before = (SELECT X.delivery FROM delivery X WHERE X.delivery_id < NEW.delivery_id ORDER BY X.delivery_id DESC LIMIT 1);

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER trigger_on_insert
 
 BEFORE INSERT 
 ON `delivery` 
 
 FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN 
  DECLARE before INT;
        SET before = (SELECT X.delivery FROM delivery X WHERE X.delivery_id < NEW.delivery_id ORDER BY X.delivery_id DESC LIMIT 1);
  SET NEW.delivery_col = before;

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `MAX()` function to get the maximum value and add 1 to it, e.g.:

```
set before = SELECT MAX(delivery) FROM delivery;
set NEW.delivery_col = before + 1;
```

Or

```
set NEW.delivery_col = SELECT MAX(delivery) + 1 FROM delivery;
```

Comment: You are selecting the delivery_id but I need to select the delivery column.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with the code you pasted above in the comment.

- It doesn't add 1 to before.
- You need to use a different delimiter when defining a trigger so the delimiters get included in the trigger.
- Use back-tick marks to quote variable, column, and table names to avoid conflicts with reserved words

Give this a try:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_on_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `delivery` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE `before` INT; 
    SET `before` = (SELECT X.`delivery` FROM `delivery` X WHERE X.`delivery_id` < NEW.`delivery_id` ORDER BY X.`delivery_id` DESC LIMIT 1); 
    SET NEW.`delivery_col` = `before` + 1;
END|

DELIMITER ;
```